# Mat-datepicker-toggle showing behind modal and not in here position

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Helloo, I have a problem on my view using angular 7 and bootstrap 4. When I click on open to show calendar. It's showing behind my modal and show in the left. How can i fix the probleme?

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljVts.png)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77KOy.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="modal-body">

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="myDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<mat-form-field>
     <input formControlName="dateFrom
     Selector" matInput
                      [matDatepicker]="pickerDateFromSelector" placeholder="Please Select Date">
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerDateFromSelector"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #pickerDateFromSelector></mat-datepicker>
                    </mat-form-field>
```

```
Selector"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   <mat-datepicker #pickerDateSelector></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to CSS worked for me. I am using Angular 8 and Angular Material 8.2.3

```
.cdk-overlay-container{
  z-index: 2000;
}
```